# run same command on multiple tabs of a terminal gnome-terminal

Tags: linux, terminal, gnome-terminal

Every day I run same ssh(succeeded by entering password) on 3 or more terminals. Is there any way to run same command parallely on all the terminal tabs opened on gnome-terminal. It can be ssh or cd any any other command. I know this feature is there in Konsole(from KDE) but not in gnome-terminal.
Thanks

Comment: GNU screen has this builtin. Also, look at Puppet or similar tools. Voting to move to [SU]. Also, use public key authentication and make it a batch script. You can still enter a passphrase using ssh-agent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Terminator terminal supports the function you are looking for. You can find more information  [here](http://www.tenshu.net/p/terminator.html). I am using this program every day. It is a very useful piece of software.

Comment: Yes terminator has worked....But also can you tell me hot to set individual titles for each tab like in gnome-terminal. I couldn't find. Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 3):

To open tabs in gnome-terminal with a predefined commands (i.e. `ssh server1`, `ssh server2`, ...) you can use a command

```
gnome-terminal --tab -e "ssh server1" --tab -e "ssh server2"
```

And, it was previously mentioned, you should use key authentication to not to enter your passwords every time, but if you can't, change your ssh command to

```
sshpass -p 'mysecretpass' ssh server1
```

In addition to this, you can create a script file with the sshpass command and pass it with the -e option while creating the terminal.. this would further simplify things.